# Query about database (mysql, oracle)

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I have some trouble with project.
I have 1 query sentence writing by mysql.
I need to change it from mysql to oracle.
The query is below,

```
select substring(ad_cde,1,18)
from advertise
where substring(ad_cde,1,18)='119821168010300222'


insert into advertise(ad_cde)
select concat('119821168010300000',lpad(convert(substring(max(ad_cde),19,3),unsigned)+1,3,'0')) as a
from advertise
where substring(ad_cde,1,18)='119821168010300000' 
and EXISTS(select * from advertise where substring(ad_cde,1,18)='119821168010300000')


insert into advertise(ad_cde)
select concat('119821168010300101',lpad(convert(substring(max(ad_cde),19,3),unsigned)+1,3,'0')) as a
from advertise
where NOT EXISTS(select * from advertise where substring(ad_cde,1,18)='119821168010300101')
```

It's really hurry because someone is teasing me.

Answer (score 0):

replace the 'mysql' functions with 'plsql' functions
substring with substr
concat with || between what you want to concatenate
and if convert is to change type to number replace it with to_number